# How to export a multilayer OpenOffice drawing to a multilayer PDF file?

Tags: pdf, export, drawing, openoffice.org

I made an OpenOffice drawing with multiple layers and would like to export this to a multilayer pdf file.
Can I do this directly or do I need auxiliary software ?
(I use Openoffice 4.1.7 on a Win10 PC)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that Scribus does the job:
It's open source desktop publishing software downloadable at [www.scribus.net](http://www.scribus.net).
I used the portabilized version 1.5.6.1 from portableapps.com.

Open Scribus and follow these steps:

1. Insert - Image Frame
2. File - Open - All supported formats - open file xxx.odg
3. Windows - Layers: Sort the layers in your preferred order
   (Items in layers on top of the list will hide items in layers down
   the list)
4. File - Export - Save as PDF: In the Preflight Verifier - Current Profile: choose PDF 1.5 or higher and click 'Ignore errors' if any.
   (Only pdf versions >= 1.5 support transparent objects)
5. Choose Compatibility: PDF 1.5 or higher, and checkmark the 'Include Layers' checkbox
   (Only pdf versions >= 1.5 support layers)
6. Click 'Save' - Done !